# Choice of symbols: $O_p(G)$, $O^p(G)$, and $O_\infty(G)$

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups, notation

For a finite group $G$ and a prime number $p$, several normal subgroups are defined as follows:

- $O_p(G)$ = the largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$ (*$p$-core*)
- $O^p(G)$ = the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ for which the quotient is a $p$-group (*$p$-residual*)
- $O_\infty(G)$ = the largest normal solvable subgroup of $G$ (*solvable radical*)

There are also $p'$ versions as well and more generally $\pi$ versions, but it doesn't matter here.

My question: why the symbol "$O$" is used in these?

Many symbols for constructing groups have obvious reasons such as $C_G(H)$ for a centralizer, $N_G(H)$ for a normalizer, $\Phi(G)$ for the Frattini subgroup, $D(G)$ for the derived subgroup, $Z(G)$ for the center (=Zentrum, a bit tricky) and so on and so forth. But I have no idea why the notation "$O$" is employed here. Do you know any reason? If there is no particular reason and it is just an accident, who started using it?

Comment: I would guess that, since the letter C is already taken by centralizers/conjugacy, so the next letter O is used?

Comment: I suspect Gorenstein may be the first to use it? I have not checked but I think that Hall and HIgman (obvious candidates to use such notation) used $P_0, N_0, P_1,\dots$ for $1, O_{p'}, O_{p'p}, \dots$; Higman still used this in 1960. Gorenstein and Walter (in their dihedral centralisers paper, c. 1962) use $O(G)$ for the  maximal normal odd order subgroup. Perhaps soon afterwards this blossomed into the full $O_{p'p}$ notation in their paper on (?) $p$-stability. (Sorry I can't remember the precise name, I always called it the $p$-amazing paper.)

Comment: Gorenstein (1980, p. 105) reads "any group $G$ possesses a unique maximal normal $p$-subgroup, which is customarily denoted by $O_p(G)$." So he (his textbook, at least) might not be the first.

Comment: @Orat, 1980 is far too late. I reckon that by 1965 it was standard notation (although I can't give an example), and I know I used it in my own thesis in 1967.

Comment: Ah, what you imply is $O(G)  (= O_{2'}(G))$ came in first, and "O" is a trace of _odd_? It is likely to happen and makes sense.

Comment: For what its worth, the notation appears in Gorenstein and Walter's "The Characterization Dihedral Sylow of Finite Groups with 2-Subgroups, part 1" (received March 1964). I'm not sure if this is the $p$-amazing paper @ancientmathematician refers to, but it is a neat $p$-paper.